# populate a form with existing data in ejs

Tags: ejs

I am trying to populate a form with existing data in ejs something like

```
<input ...name="username" value={{data.username || "" }}
```

and I use || to avoid 'undefined' if data.username is null.

How can I achieve the same in ejs ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short way using `locals` object.

```
<input ...name="username" value="<%= locals.data.username ? data.username: '' %>" >
```